# role (h) does not exist on document cudasign error

Tags: php

I'm using cudasign api to send a document and get it signed.

The document is being sent, and I successfully put a field on it with role "Buyer", but when I send the invite for that document it gives an error like the following

```
{"errors":[{"code":65536,"message":"role (h) does not exist on document"}]}
```

I've given same role(buyer) to the recipient, but it still gives the same error. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
array("to" => array("email" =>$to,
"role"=>"Buyer",
"order"=>1,
"role_id"=>""),"from" => $from,"cc"=>[],
"subject"=>$from." needs Your Signature",
"message"=>$from."invited you to sign")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of help with their support, we resolved this issue, the to array should be in a single array, like,

```
array("to" => array(array("email" =>$to,
"role"=>"Buyer",
"order"=>1,
"role_id"=>"")),"from" => $from,"cc"=>[],
"subject"=>$from." needs Your Signature",
"message"=>$from."invited you to sign")
```